# SSH Connection gets refused when executing bash script within Node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh, shelljs

So my structure looks like this:

```
main.js
folder1/
   jsFile1.js
folder2/
   jsFile2.js
   bashFile.sh
```

`main.js` requires `jsFile1.js` which then requires and runs `jsFile2.js`. `jsFile2.js` then finally runs `bashFile.sh` using ShellJS and passes three arguments.

```
shell.exec(`bash utils/sshAndCreate.sh ${ip} ${encryptedUser} ${encryptedPw}`);
```

bashFile.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
host=$1
user=$2
pw=$3

# Postdata
postdata="someUnfinishedStuff"

# Download the file to the server
ssh root@$host -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no wget http://myOtherServer/api --post-data $postdata -O bash.sh
```

My problem is that when I manually start `bashFile.sh` using `bash bashFile.sh parameter1 parameter2 parameter3` it works just fine and as expected but it doesn't work when I run `main.js` which eventually also runs the script. I just get

```
ssh: connect to host myServerIpHere port 22: Connection refused
```

What is also weird, I moved the `shell.exec` part to `jsFile1.js` and it worked a few times but when I tried again my connection also gets refused.

Note 1: I never connected to the server before, so it isn't in my `known_hosts`.

Note 2: A child_process produces the same error.

Comment: you might want to use ssh's `-i` option.  See `man ssh`.

Comment: @RedCricket, the connection still gets refused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found a solution. Even though the server *should* be ready it sometimes isn't. So I solved it by just repeating the process of connecting until the server accepts the connection.

```sh
until ssh root@$host command
do
    sleep 10
done
```